# Spring Batch Throwing an error 'Object 'BATCH_JOB_SEQ' is not a sequence object'

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working on a spring batch project, I have used sql server as a local database, used this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-sqlserver.sql) to create the db script for batches but now get below given error.

```
23463 [main] WARN  o.s.b.c.c.a.DefaultBatchConfigurer - No transaction manager was provided, using a DataSourceTransactionManager 
24014 [main] WARN  o.s.b.a.o.j.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning 
92338 [HikariPool-2 housekeeper] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-2 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=49s173ms145µs619ns). 
102416 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=1m969ms212µs331ns). 
102682 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain sequence value; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Object 'BATCH_JOB_SEQ' is not a sequence object.] with root cause
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Object 'BATCH_JOB_SEQ' is not a sequence object.
```

When I call the SQL query

```
SELECT name, type_desc FROM sys.objects WHERE name=N'BATCH_JOB_SEQ';
```

The returned result is

```
Name:             type_desc:
BATCH_JOB_SEQ    SEQUENCE_OBJECT
```

Comment: If it didn't exist it would return `Invalid object name 'BATCH_JOB_SEQ'.` So clearly it exists but is not a sequence. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74384100/edit) your question to include the results from `SELECT name, type_desc FROM sys.objects WHERE name=N'BATCH_JOB_SEQ';`.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Batch 4, tables were used to emulate sequences for SQL Server and a `SqlServerMaxValueIncrementer` was used to increment IDs.

In Spring Batch v5, we changed SQL Server support to use sequences instead of emulating them with tables. Version 5 uses a `SqlServerSequenceMaxValueIncrementer` to increment IDs.

The link you shared points to the DDL script of the `main` branch, which is for Spring Batch v5. So in your case, you either need to use the DDL script for v4 (which you can find [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/4.3.7/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-sqlserver.sql)), or upgrade your application to Spring Batch 5 (the last version is `5.0.0-RC2`, the GA is planned later this November 2022).

Comment: I tried v4 script but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because Up until v4, the DDL script for MS SQLServer used tables to emulate sequences. In Spring Batch 5, this usage has been updated with real sequences.

To resolve the above error you need to update a few things on DDL schema. A detailed account of what is to be done is mentioned here : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#ms-sqlserver

Implementing the changes mentioned in the above link I was able to resolve the same error.

To read more on what's new in Spring Batch 5 :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/whatsnew.html#whatsNew

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).